# Grammaticality of "who fell to earth, shattering the land"

Tags: gerunds, relative-clauses, participles

While watching Youtube videos, I recently came across this sentence

> Their quarrel turned to rage and their violent struggle darkened the skies,          until the Dragon of the South Wind struck down his brother, **who fell to earth, shattering the land**.

"Who fell to earth, shattering the land." Is this a grammatically correct sentence? It appears like quite poetic language. What exact rule is this? and if so, do you have any additional examples?

Edit: Apparently this is a special adjective clause. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with this special chase. Any examples?

Comment: You are correct that is is poetic (and what's more, mythic) language.

Comment: @JohnFeltz is see, thank you. Do you maybe have any additional examples or rules i have to heed when applying this kind of english.?Because I might consider using this form aswell :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sentence is correct.

To make grammar-checking easier, you should split the sentence in simpler sentences.

> Their quarrel turned to rage and their violent struggle darkened the skies, until the Dragon of the South Wind struck down his brother, who fell to earth, shattering the land.

Becomes (replacing *who* by *his brother*) :

> Their quarrel turned to rage and their violent struggle darkened the skies, until the Dragon of the South Wind struck down his brother.
>
> *His brother* fell to earth, shattering the land.

Both of these sentences are correct, and the second is made an [adjective clause](http://www.myenglishteacher.net/adjectiveclauses.html) correctly, so the final sentence is correct.

Comment: I think the sentences could be split even more, but it didn't feel useful. Also, I made this answer community wiki because I feel like it isn't detailed enough and would gladly have some more backup

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. After reading through the mentioned link I noticed that there is no real example conforming to my example. Do you have any additional examples? Thanks